# Fossil svn: linking tickets to a branch

Tags: fossil

I have 2 branches in my Fossil repository: is it possible to link a ticket only to one of the two branches, so that in the timeline view you can understand which branch a ticket belongs to?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In ticket title write "for branch A"

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. The only thing you need to make sure is that you include the correct reference. In the screenshot below, you see that I made a ticket where I wrote in the ticket title:

```
Test reference to branch [94558ab315732e3f]
```

That reference is the object-id of the branch I am making the reference to. Look at the screenshot below:

[image: References in the timeline]

See that I took the ID that is placed in front of the word "Leaf" and identifies the branch. On top, in the sam screenshot you now see the line "Test reference to branch [94558ab315732e3f]" where the branch ID is clickable. It will take you to the branch description

You will not have this clickable behaviour in the Ticket itself. If will appear as normal text:

[image]

If you look carefully at the screenshot of the timeline, you will see that I started to test this the other way round: add a branch that has the ticket-ID as name. To that the only thing you need to do differently is that you quote the ticket name when creating the branch. So:

```
fossil branch new "[c98dd264f1319]" trunk
```

and not:

```
fossil branch new [c98dd264f1319] trunk
```

When you do that, in your branches list you will have an item named `[c98dd264f1319]` that you can click on to go directly to the relevant ticket. Both referencing branches to tickets and referncing tickets to branches are very useful to keep all changes referenced. It makes the Fossil timeline even more useful than it already is.

One last thing: when you name branches like this, at least in zsh you will need to update with the quotes again. So:

```
fossil update "[c98dd264f1319]"
```

works fine, but

```
fossil update [c98dd264f1319]
```

will give a "not found" errors (in zsh). You will probably get used to adding the quotes in no time.